# Substitute for marjoram

Tags: substitutions, herbs

Are there any herbs similar to or anything i can substitute marjoram with?

Comment: Interesting question.. Which recipe do you require majoram for? Sadly I have never had a chance to get a good grip of the flavor and taste of Marjoram..

Comment: Chicken marsala!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*Marjoram* is a type of **Oregano**, or rather it is from the *Origanum* family (*origanum majorana*, oregano is *origanum vulgare*).  So oregano makes the closest substitute I find, though it is stronger, so use less, oregano is often called *wild marjoram*.

Answer (score 11):

A great resource on spices is Gernot Katzer's website. The [majoram](http://www.uni-graz.at/~katzer/engl/Maio_hor.html) page plus my own experience make me suggest **sage** (for the slightly bitter note) and **thyme**. I would not use oregano - to my Italian nose it smells very different.

Comment: Looks like the webpage is gone ... but Archive.org's Wayback Machine has it: https://web.archive.org/web/20120609184738/https:/www.uni-graz.at/~katzer/engl/Maio_hor.html

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are just out of any types of marjorams (wild, oregano, otherwise) the spice coriander can be substituted in the less-herbal (where you would swing with **sage**) categories, i.e. poultry or eggs.

If you are adding marjoram to something with elements akin to smoked paprika, red pepper, here is where coriander comes in handy. I find it matches well with beef, venison, tomato particularly well. You need to tie the coriander's higher piques down though to emulate marjoram (which is more even in its notes); you can do this with thyme as suggested above, or *maybe* tarragon (though that can be pretty risky itself).

Answer (score 2):

Not a close match, but sage can impart the same hint of smokiness, and I've used it from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a substitute for marjoram for a herbal rice recipe. I used oregano and was very pleased with the outcome. It gave the rice an slightly earthy taste. Very good I must say.

Comment: Please do not repeat answers already given.